# DataGridView Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm showing database records through a DataGridView in a WinForms application. Also , i have a textview , a combobox and a datetimepicker. How can i sort the datagridview to show only records which equals the textview or the combobox or datetimepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

You need the `BindingSource` between your, for example, `DataSet` and your `DataGridView`.

With a BindingSource you are able to filter your DataSource because the BindingSource has a `.Filter` property.

If you change the filter, it will filter your `DataGridView` too.

> **BindingSource.Filter** Gets or sets the expression used to filter which rows are viewed.

#### Sample

#### Add the BindingSource from the ToolBox, this is only a sample

```
BindingSource myBindingSource = new BindingSource();
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable;
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource;

myBindingSource.Filter =// your filter
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - How to: Bind Data to the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx)
- [MSDN - BindingSource Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx)
- [Exploring Secrets of BindingSource Filters - Learn how to give users fast DataGridView filtering power so they can hone in on the data they're truly interested in.](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34451/1954)